# Change localhost with custom port to a fake domain

Tags: iis, dns, localhost

I have three localhost site with different port..

localhost:80
localhost:81
localhost:82

I want to make fake domains for each site, instead of type `localhost:80` on browser, I would like to use a fake domain (such as `www.myweb.com`)..

I already tried edit the hosts file in `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc`..

I add a line `127.0.0.1:81 www.firstfakedomain.com` 
to the hosts file

But it doesn't works!

is it any configuration to be made in this box...

[image]

Comment: did you created a binding in IIS for your site like www.myweb.com ?

Comment: @Hakunamatata i just editted my post.... did you mean the field in the picture above? i try assigned the hostname...but it doens't works.... is it will took time?

Comment: Add your site url as host name .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your host file don;t specify port number.  Your host file should have entry like like below

```
127.0.0.1  test1.com.au
127.0.0.1  test2.com.au
```

In your IIS application specify host name as test1.com.au and test2.com.au for your applications on port 80.

Comment: and how is he going to access all three different sites then ?

Comment: thanks! i already tried...and it works!! but i have a question, so even if in same port, we are still able to differentiate those three sites with different hostname?       
i'm sorry, i actually didn't understand about the hostname and port..

Comment: so how about the localhost:8080 that is from Apache/PHP(wampserver)..
how to change the hostname?

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien  ... IIS host header takes care of it.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: @Ash .. IIS host header take care of it. That is how you can use one IIS to host multiple web applications on same port. http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/understanding_host_headers.htm

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien ... you need to specify your site name in hosts file and then modify configuration file for Apache. Not sure what to do in Apache though...

Comment: it worked, it added it in hosts file then in IIS bindings

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, port numbers are not for the host file resolution of domains.
You can do this configuring the fiddler host.

*Go to Fiddler2 menu:- Tools > HOSTS*

and then modify it for the IP address you want.

*127.0.0.1:81 www.firstfakedomain.com*

Save it and try this in browser.

Comment: what is fiddler host ?

Comment: Install fiddler 2 https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler2 and then go to menu -> tools - hosts...